# Updating weights in basic neural network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

**Problem:**

I'm new to neural networks topic and today wanted to learn how to make my neural network to learn.
I'm trying to do an exercise found in the internet.
The sum of errors for all series should be:
`1.501535` but I am getting `7.394650000000001`, so I thought that my weights are not updating. And that's exactly the issue, but I have no idea how to update the weights correctly.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

def calculate(input_numbers: list[float], weights: np.array, iterations: int, alpha: float, goal: list[float]):
        num_rows, num_cols = weights.shape
        if not len(input_numbers) == num_cols:
            print("Wrong matrix")
            return 0
            
        error = 0
        prediction = np.dot(input_numbers, np.transpose(weights))
        delta = prediction - goal
        weights_delta = np.outer(delta, input_numbers)
        weights = weights - (weights_delta * alpha)
        error = error + (pow(prediction - goal, 2))
        print("\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SUMMARY XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        print("delta :" + str(delta))
        print("weights_delta :" + str(weights_delta))
        print("Weights : " + str(weights))
        print("error : " + str(error))
            
        return np.sum(error)

input_1 = [8.5, 0.65, 1.2]
goal_1 = [0.1, 1, 0.1]
input_2 = [9.5, 0.8, 1.3]
goal_2 = [0, 1, 0]
input_3 = [9.9, 0.8, 0.5]
goal_3 = [0, 0, 0.1]
input_4 = [9.0, 0.9, 1.0]
goal_4 = [0.1, 1, 0.2]

weights_matrix = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, -0.3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.0], [0.0, 1.3, 0.1]])
for x in range(50):
    print("\nITERATION: ", x)
    error_sum = calculate(input_1, weights_matrix, 1, 0.01, goal_1)
    error_sum = error_sum + calculate(input_2, weights_matrix, 1, 0.01, goal_2)
    error_sum = error_sum + calculate(input_3, weights_matrix, 1, 0.01, goal_3)
    error_sum = error_sum + calculate(input_4, weights_matrix, 1, 0.01, goal_4)

print("TOTAL ERROR: ", error_sum)
```

Would someone be so kind to guide me on where and how I should update the weights? I have tried returning `weights` in `calculate()`, but results were totally wrong, so I guess it should be done in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, I don't know why this is a thing, probably something to do with value assignment. Like, in the first case, it defines a *new* variable `weights`, and in the second line it changes the array you've passed.

Anyway, change

`weights = weights - (weights_delta * alpha)`

to

`weights -= (weights_delta * alpha)`